# Full Screen game window wont display correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

Hello i am trying to Create the beginning of a full screen game and i am having issues. I want a blue background with white text and the entire screen to be changed to 800*600. The problem is i get a screen with an 800*600 box in the middle(not visible but i can tell by mouse boundaries) and my background is black.

---

[image]

---

My Code:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 * Write a description of class Full here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Full extends JFrame 
{

   public static void main(String[] args){
     DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);  
     Full full = new Full();
     full.run(dm);

    }
   public void run(DisplayMode dm){
     setBackground(Color.BLUE);  
     setForeground(Color.WHITE);
     setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,24));

     Screen s = new Screen();
     try{
        s.setFullScreen(dm,this);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        }finally{
         s.restoreScreen();   
        }
    }
   public void paint(Graphics g){
       if(g instanceof Graphics2D){
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
       g.drawString("This is gonna be awesome!!",200,200);
    }
}

public class Screen
{
  private GraphicsDevice vc;
  Window myWindow;
  public Screen(){
      GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }
  public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame myWindow){
      myWindow.setUndecorated(true);
      myWindow.setResizable(false);
      vc.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow);

      if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
          try{
             vc.setDisplayMode(dm); 
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
  public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
      return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    }
  public void restoreScreen(){
      Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
      if(w != null){
          w.dispose();
        }
      vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short answer, because it seems that you are on the wrong trace :)

Games should be using OpenGL or DirectX, so the graphical work is done by the GPU. I strongly recommend OpenGL, since it is compatible with every platform. The way you started, the game will run completely on the CPU, which is not good.

Take a look at [LWJGL (LightWeight Java Game Library)](http://lwjgl.org). It is a cross-platform library that allows you to use OpenGL. It will require some Googling for tutorials, but it is really worth it. Your performance of the game will be a lot better, and your game will be made the way it has to be. Just to give you an idea, Minecraft is made with LWJGL.

OpenGL allows you to make a quick start with your game development, using some simple methods, which is good first a first game experience. Later on, you will find out how to do things more efficient, but that would be too much information to start of with :D
Good luck!